# How to create a multi-dimensional array and have a property attached to a class determine where values are in the array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array as a sort of 2D map for a text-based RPG game. I want to create a multidimensional array that's, for example, 5x5. The array would be filled with 0s to represent a space void of an object. Other numbers would represent the `player` on the map, an `enemy`, an `npc`, a `skill-object` (like an enchantment table, etc.), `doors` that link to maps, and `chests`. They would all have different values to represent what object is there. If a `player` tries walking into a `chest`, it would instead loot the `chest`. Then the `chest` would be reset to 0 to represent the empty space, letting the `player` walk there and representing that there is no more chest. If the `player` tries walking over an `enemy`, it would instead engage combat (handled by a separate class and functions). Walking over a number representing a `door` would link to another multidimensional array that represents another map.

I want to know what kind of property I need to put inside the `player` class to handle where he is on the map. A function would then change that value to move him around the map. Would creating a class for a map be a good idea? Would I store the values for the objects there or in the individual classes for those objects? How would I go about this? Thank you for your help. For reference, here's my player class (careful, it's long...):

```
public class Player
{
    public string   name        { get; set; }        //Name of Player
    public int      level       { get; set; }        //Player's combat level         (average of combat-related skills' levels)
    public int      health      { get; set; }        //Player's health               (player dies when this value reaches 0)
    public int      health_max  { get; set; }        //Player's maximum health
    public int      stamina     { get; set; }        //Player's stamina              (used for power attacks, slowly recharges on own)
    public int      stamina_max { get; set; }        //Player's maxiumum stamina
    public int      fatigue     { get; set; }        //Player's fatigue rate         (player cannot fight or run while fatigue is 100)
    public int      hunger      { get; set; }        //Player's hunger level         (player becomes weaker as hunger increases)
    public int      style       { get; set; }        //Player's fighting style       (refer to styles.txt)
    //THIEVERY SKILLS - LOCKPICKING / LOCK_P, LUCK / LUCK, PICKPOCKETING / PICK_P, SNEAKING / SNEAK
    skill LOCK_P    = new skill();      //Ability to pick locks to open locked doors or chests. Trained by unlocking locks successfully. Higher level, better locks.
    skill LUCK      = new skill();      //The higher the level, the more lucky. Loot from enemies, dungeons, and chests are better. Higher level, higher crit chance. Leveled up 3 times every time your overall thievery levels up.
    skill PICK_P    = new skill();      //Ability to steal from NPCs' pockets without turning them against you. Trained by sucessfully stealing items.
    skill SNEAK     = new skill();      //Ability to move unseen. 25% of your sneak level boosts your pickpocketing level. 100% crit chance with an attack from sneaking. Trained by sneaking / escaping combat.
    //COMBAT SKILLS - MELEE / MELEE, SORCERY / SOR, MAGICKA / MAGICKA, ARCHERY / ARCHERY, HEAVY ARMOR / H_ARM, LIGHT ARMOR / L_ARM
    skill MELEE     = new skill();      //Ability to fight better with melee weapons in combat. Trained by dealing damage with melee weapons.
    skill SOR       = new skill();      //Ability to fight better with sorcerey and spells in combat. Trained by dealing damage with spells.
    skill MAGICKA   = new skill();      //Affects how many spells you can cast before you must regenerate your magicka pool. Trained by casting spells.
    skill ARCHERY   = new skill();      //Ability to fight better with ranged weapons, like bows, in combat. Trained by dealing damage with ranged weapons.
    skill H_ARM     = new skill();      //Affects how effective wearing heavy armor, like metal armor, is. Trained by taking damage while wearing heavy armor.
    skill L_ARM     = new skill();      //Affects how effective wearing light armor, like leather armor, is. Trained by taking damage while wearing light armor.
    //CRAFTSHIP SKILLS - SMITHING / SMITH, CRAFTING / CRAFT, ENCHANTMENT / ENCH, HERBLORE / HERB, FLETCHING / FLETCH
    skill SMITH     = new skill();      //Ability to create heavy armor and forge melee weapons. Trained by creating mentioned items.
    skill CRAFT     = new skill();      //Ability to create jewlery to be enchanted. Trained by creating jewlery.
    skill ENCH      = new skill();      //Ability to enchant items so that they give stat boosts to the wearer. Trained by enchanting items.
    skill HERB      = new skill();      //Ability to create potions from collected materials and plants. Trained by creating potions.
    skill FLETCH    = new skill();      //Ability to create bows, arrows, and crossbow stocks. Trained by creating mentioned items.
    //MISC. SKILLS - AGILITY / AGILITY, MINING / MINING, WOODCUTTING / WOOD_C, COOKING / COOK, SLAYER / SLAY
    skill AGILITY   = new skill();      //Ability to pass obstacles. Trained by passing obstacles.
    skill MINING    = new skill();      //Ability to mine ore from ore veins to be used in smithing. Trained by mining ore.
    skill WOOD_C    = new skill();      //Ability to cut wood from trees and vines to be used in fletching. Trained by cutting wood.
    skill COOK      = new skill();      //Ability to cook food to feed hunger / heal health.
    skill SLAY      = new skill();      //The knowledge of how to slay advanced monsters using special equipment. Trained by completeing tasks.

    public void set_all_skills()        //Function to set values for all skills. Called once at beginning of game.
    {
        string[] names = { "Thievery", "Combat", "Craftship", "Misc" };     //Group names for skills
        skill[] skills = { LOCK_P, LUCK, PICK_P, SNEAK, MELEE, SOR, MAGICKA, ARCHERY, H_ARM, L_ARM, SMITH, CRAFT, ENCH, HERB, FLETCH, AGILITY, MINING, WOOD_C, COOK, SLAY };    //Array of all the player's skills
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)    { skills[i].set_level(1); }       //For loop to set each level at 1 (for base values).
        int counter = 0, name = 0;                                        //Creates variables for the while loop to set tag names.
        while (counter < 20)                                              //While loop to set tag names of each skill.
        {
            if (counter < 4)                        { skills[counter].set_tag(names[0]); }      //First 4 skills are given the first tag
            if (counter > 4 && counter < 11)        { skills[counter].set_tag(names[1]); }      //Next 6 skills are given the second tag
            if (counter > 11 && counter < 16)       { skills[counter].set_tag(names[2]); }      //Next 5 skills are given the third tag
            if (counter > 16 && counter < 21)       { skills[counter].set_tag(names[3]); }      //Last 5 skills are given the last tag
            counter++;                                                                          //Increment the counter by 1.
        }
    }

    //Health / Stamina Alteration Functions
    public void     take_blunt_damage(int dmg)            { this.health -= dmg; }           //Decrement player's health by the value of `dmg`
    public void     take_weak_damage(int dmg, int weak)   { this.health -= dmg + weak; }  //Take this dmg if the player is weak to the enemy's type of attack
    public void     take_strong_damage(int dmg, int str)  { this.health -= dmg - str; }   //Take this dmg if the player is strong to the enemy's type of attack
    public void     heal(int x)                           { this.health += x; }           //Increment player's health by `x` amount
    public void     heal()                                { this.health = health_max; }   //Fully heal the player
    public void     die()                                 { this.health = 0; }            //Kill the player by setting health to 0
    public void     dec_stamina(int x)                    { this.stamina -= x; }          //Decrement player's stamina by `x` amount
    public void     fill_stamina(int x)                   { this.stamina += x; }          //Increment player's stamina by `x` amount
    public void     fill_stamina()                        { this.stamina = stamina_max; } //Fully fill the player's stamina
    //Stat Alteration
    public void     lvl_stat(int x, skill s)    { s.level_up_x(x); }            //Level up skill `s` by `x` levels
    public void     lvl_stat(skill s)           { s.level_up(); }               //Level up skill `s` once
}
```

And for those who want it for reference, here's my `skill` class:

```
 public class skill
{
    public string       tag                     { get; set; }               //Tags a sub-skill to a major-skill
    public int          level                   { get; set; }               //Level of the skill    (average of sub-skills' levels)
    public int          XP                      { get; set; }               //XP towards leveling up
    public int[]        XP_to_level_up          = { 50, 120, 200, 350, 420, 500, 650, 720, 800, 950, 1020, 2000, 3500, 4200, 5000, 6500, 7200, 8000, 9500, 10200, 11000, 12500, 13200, 14000, 15500 };               //XP needed to level up
    public void         set_tag(string tag)     { this.tag = tag; }                     //Sets the tag of the skill
    public void         set_level(int x)        { this.level = x; }                     //Set this level to int x
    public bool         level_up()              { this.level++; return true; }          //Increment this level by 1
    public bool         level_up_x(int x)       { this.level += x; return true; }       //Increment this level by int x
    public void         add_XP(int x)           { this.XP += x; }                       //Add XP towards the next level
    public int          calc_where_on_array(int level, int[] XP_to_level_up)            //Calculate what int on the array based on your level
    {
        return XP_to_level_up[level];
    }
    public bool         check_XP(int XP, int where_on_array, int[] XP_to_level_up)      //Check if the current XP you have can level you up
    {
        if (XP >= XP_to_level_up[where_on_array])       //If current XP is greater than what is needed to level up...
        { 
            this.level_up();                            //... level this skill up.
            return true;                                //Return true, to show that you successfully leveled up.
        }
        else { return false; }                          //If you cannot level up, return false.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know   http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: First thing to learn about: naming conventions. Next thing: collections. (I'd really recommend against having such a huge list of fields here...)

Comment: Tim, I did not know about that. That you for informing me. Jon, I don't know what you mean. I have naming conventions, there's a `tag` property on all skills to represent where they derive from, everything's spread-out and readable, and there's comments on almost everything...

Comment: Jon Skeet is just saying that you should use a collection object to house your skills.

You could even have a collection for each category of skills:

public IEnumerable<skill> Thivery { get; set; } would be an example of a collection that houses skills with the naming of thivery so you know what type of skills.

You could also make a base class or interface called skill and inherit from that to make different type of skills.

Comment: Ah. I'm not very advanced in C# so I have no idea what a collection is or the code you put, so I'm going to look it up now and learn about it. Thank you, now I know for the future. EDIT: I already have a class called 'skill' that they all inherit from, filled with all their properties and functions.

Comment: @AnthonyHackett OMG you seriously need to improve your code. Read up on Collections and `Enums` in C#. and please honor the C# naming conventions, where your property names should be `ProperCased`.

Comment: Also, instead of a MultiDimensional array, create a `Location` class (or struct) with `X,Y` values so you can assign that to your `Player`s, instead of the horrible `array[,]` Syntax.

Comment: HighCore I have difficulty reading words close together so the underscore spaces out the words for me and I can read it a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can define your 2d map array like this:

```
int[,] map = new int[5, 5];
```

See [MSDN on Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) for more.  Yes I would suggest putting the map into a class although if you are just learning this stuff do whatever you can to cobble it together in the short term I guess!

Second, I think your player could have an X, Y position.  So keeping with your style above, maybe add this to your player class:

```
public int      x_pos { get; set; }
public int      y_pos { get; set; }
```

You can then use a function to update his location and afterward say map[player.x_pos, player.y_pos] = 1, or whatever the code for "player" is.

Third, consider that maybe a square on your map has lava.  And a monster is standing there.  Or a certain square is shallow water, and the player is standing there.  How do you plan to handle having multiple things on one square?  Your current design has a bit of a limitation there.  It can get ridiculous: Maybe you have a square that has a darkness spell cast on it, with a cloud of poison gas floating there, along with 10 gold pieces on the ground, which is made of smooth marble with some moss on it, and there is a goblin sleeping there.

If I understand your project correctly, many of the things you will be trying to do will be discussed here at [Rogue Basin](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).  I would advise you poke around in there and see if anything is useful for you.

Finally, your code with the skill[] skills full of hard-coded skills is not really the way most programmers would handle it.  I would echo Jon Skeet's comment that you should look into collections.

Best of luck, I think you'll have some fun playing around with your project.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely have my research cut out for me now. I'm going to go no-life some text-books and guides about what you guys all said and see what I come up with. Thank you.

Comment: Try this link:http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=How_to_Write_a_Roguelike_in_15_Steps